# Launching ListenableFuture within FutureCallback and calling back when all are complete

Tags: java, guava

I'm trying to have a nested layer of callbacks for ListenableFutures, something like this:

```
ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));

ListenableFuture<A> futureA = service.submit(() -> a.doSomething());

Futures.addCallback(futureA, new FutureCallback<A>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(A result) {
         ListenableFuture<B> futureB = service.submit(() -> b.doSomething(result)
    }
});
```

How do I add a callback when both `futureA` and `futureB` complete?

This is a simple example but I'm looking for a solution that may have multiple layers of `ListenableFuture`.

Comment: `allAsList`?  http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably creating a new future with `allAsList` might be an option. (I assume you do not mind starting both `a` and `b` together.)

```
//No idea how A and B are related, so I assume Object
ListenableFuture<List<? extends Object>> futureAB = Futures.allAsList(futureA, futureB);
Futures.addCallback(futureAB, ...);
```

Following the update:

```
ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));

ListenableFuture<A> futureA = service.submit(() -> a.doSomething());

Futures.addCallback(futureA, new FutureCallback<A>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final A result) {
         ListenableFuture<B> futureB = service.submit(() -> b.doSomething(result);
         Futures.addCallback(futureB, new FutureCallback<B>() {
              ©Override
              public void onSuccess(final B resultB) {
                  //Do something with result and resultB.
              }
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: I edited my question so that futureB depends on the result of futureA. futureB then doesn't exist until futureA finishes, any suggestions in this case?

Comment: You can add the callback on `futureB` after you submitted it in the callback of `futureA`.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I found that things got really convoluted with doing complex workflows. The Java 8 `CompletableFuture` builder-style interface is working very well for this problem of multi-layered task execution.

Comment: In Scala I hardly ever create callbacks. `map`s, `flatMap`s works better. The chapter 12 of Functional Programming in Scala (http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/excerpt_contents.html) explains why this `flatMap`-like (monadic) expression cannot be expressed in terms of `traverse`. I would suggest evaluating `flatMap` for this kind of use case (with for comprehensions).